How to disable turning screen off based on proximity / light sensor?
Problem: Android 13.0.0 turns screen off based on proximity / light sensor.
How to disable turning screen off based on proximity / light sensor?
I've already tried to find a dedicated setting by searching for "proximity", "light", "sensor", but couldn't find a dedicated setting.

The screen turning off due to proximity is usually controlled by an app (e.g. phone/dialer apps). Are you facing this problem in general, or only on a specific app? Also, in case it matters, could you also mention the device model? AFAIK, there are no specific settings for sensors in Android in general, other than possibly turning off/on the whole sensors.
